# Randomize items in rmarkdown transparently

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have the following rmarkdown document:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: '2022-04-28'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

1. This is the first outer item.
    (a) A
    (b) B
2. This is the second outer item.
    (a) C
    (b) D
3. This is the third outer item.
    (a) E
    (b) F
````

I would like to randomly shuffle this list simultaneously in two ways: Inside the inner lists and outside those. Say, I want to get something like the following:

```
1. This is the second outer item. 
    (a) D 
    (b) A 
2. This is the first outer item. 
    (a) B 
    (b) A 
3. This is the third outer item. 
    (a) F 
    (b) E
```

I know that I could accomplish that by creating the rmarkdown code by programming with strings. So, my question is: Can one achieve the goal by writing the text of the document without having to resort to programming with strings? The reason is that I would like to have a clear picture of the document as I write it, without having the text of the document buried in code. (I am aware that some programming is unavoidable though.)

Comment: Also take a look at this source: https://www.mzes.uni-mannheim.de/socialsciencedatalab/article/indiv-quant-exams/

Comment: I'd do it as follows:  Write your text just as you did above, and have a function convert that into a structure like a list of lists.  Then randomize the list of lists, and convert back to text.  Don't forget to save the answer key!

Comment: Thanks, @user2554330! And do you write the questions in a separate text file? Or do you do everything inside the rmarkdown file?

Comment: I've just posted an answer that shows the code for the first conversion, along with a variable that holds the text of the questions.  I'd put it all in one file, but if you've got a long enough test, it might make sense to put the questions in a separate file and use `readLines()` to read them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it as follows: Write your text just as you did above, and have a function convert that into a structure like a list of lists. Then randomize the list of lists, and convert back to text. Don't forget to save the answer key!  Here's an example for the first conversion:

```r
questions <- "
1. This is the first outer item.
    (a) A
    (b) B
2. This is the second outer item.
    (a) C
    (b) D
3. This is the third outer item.
    (a) E
    (b) F
"

toListOfLists <- function(text) {
  text <- unlist(strsplit(text, "\n"))
  # These regular expressions match the first line of a question
  # or an answer.  \\1 will be the text.
  qreg <- "^[[:digit:]]+[.](.*)"
  areg <- "^[[:space:]]*[(][[:alpha:]][)](.*)"
 
  qstart <- grep(qreg, text)
  astart <- grep(areg, text)
  class <- rep("", length(text))
  class[qstart] <- "q"
  class[astart] <- "a"
  
  result <- list()
  for (i in seq_along(qstart)) {
    line <- qstart[i]
    question <- sub(qreg, "\\1", text[line])
    line <- line + 1
    while (line < length(text) & class[line] == "") {
      question <- paste(question, text[line], sep="\n")
      line <- line + 1
    }
    this_astart <- astart[astart >= line]
    if (line < max(qstart))
      this_astart <- this_astart[this_astart < min(qstart[qstart > line])]
    answers <- list()
    for (j in seq_along(this_astart)) {
      line <- this_astart[j]
      answers[[j]] <- sub(areg, "\\1", text[line])
      line <- line + 1
      while (line < length(text) & class[line] == "")
        answers[[j]] <- paste(answers[[j]], text[line], sep="\n")
    }
    result[[i]] <- list(question = question, answers = answers)
  }
  result
}

toListOfLists(questions)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$question
#> [1] " This is the first outer item."
#> 
#> [[1]]$answers
#> [[1]]$answers[[1]]
#> [1] " A"
#> 
#> [[1]]$answers[[2]]
#> [1] " B"
#> 
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$question
#> [1] " This is the second outer item."
#> 
#> [[2]]$answers
#> [[2]]$answers[[1]]
#> [1] " C"
#> 
#> [[2]]$answers[[2]]
#> [1] " D"
#> 
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]]$question
#> [1] " This is the third outer item."
#> 
#> [[3]]$answers
#> [[3]]$answers[[1]]
#> [1] " E"
#> 
#> [[3]]$answers[[2]]
#> [1] " F"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Something like your existing solution for the randomization and conversion back to text will work on this structure.

Comment: Thanks, @user2554330, for your example! That is a really interesting approach that opens up the possibility of writing the document in LyX, exporting it to LaTeX and then to the list of lists. To write the document in LyX is much easier than using LaTeX directly. Moreover, in my case, I will be sometimes using the `multicol` LaTeX package inside enumerate, which forces me to use LaTeX instead of markdown.

Comment: As long as it's easy to recognize the start of questions and answers, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the solution is to use  latex. An example where the answers are randomized is shown below. But I am not able to randomize the Questions as well. Maybe a deeper look into the manual can bring up a solution.

```
---
title: "List Randomize"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{randomlist}
output: pdf_document
---

## Test randomize

Eine Liste, randomisiert:

\begin{enumerate}
\item Question 1
  \RandomEnumerateList{
  answer1}{
  answer2}{
  answer3}
\item Question 2
  \RandomItemizeList{
  answer1}{
  answer2}{
  answer3}
\end{enumerate}

Package randomlist: https://ctan.joethei.xyz/macros/generic/randomlist/randomlist.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks, @Lucas. Unfortunately, I need the questions to be randomize and not only answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best that I have achieved until now:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: '2022-04-28'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r include=FALSE}
questions <- list(
  question1 = list(
    enun = "This is the first outer item.",
    ans1 = "A.",
    ans2 = "B.",
    ans3 = "X.",
    ans4 = "Y."
  ),
  question2 = list(
    enun = "This is the second outer item.",
    ans1 = "C.",
    ans2 = "D."
  ),
    question3 = list(
    enun = "This is the thrid outer item.",
    ans1 = "E.",
    ans2 = "F."
  )
)
```

```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
qexpand <- function(x)
{
  s1 <- str_c("1. ", x[[1]])
  s2 <- map_chr(sample(2:length(x)), ~ str_c( "\n    (a) ", x[[.x]])) %>% 
        str_c(collapse = " ")
  
  str_c(s1, s2)
}

scr <- map(questions[c(3,1,2)], qexpand)

res = knitr::knit_child(text = scr, quiet = TRUE, )

cat(res, sep="\n")
```
````

[image]